# Qual a diferença entre jagged arrays e multidimensional arrays, e qual a aplicação indicada para cada um?

Tags: c#, .net, array, array-multidimensional

Gostaria de entender melhor a diferença entre jagged arrays e multidimensional arrays, e como cada tipo deve ser aplicado na prática.